# Linux C++ VS Code not able to find Libraries

Tags: visual-studio-code, g++, ld

i have trouble building my c++ code in VS Code. For some reason, i can compile my code using g++ in a linux terminal, but when i try building my project in VS Code to debug it, it says that it cannot find my "boost" library. I have added the path in the tasks.json by adding `-Lpath/to/dir` and `-lboost` to the arguments. I also added the `-verbose` argument to see what the output is.

The ouput looks like this:

```
attempt to open /usr/include/libboost.so failed

attempt to open /usr/include/libboost.a failed

attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libboost.so failed
```

The output is longer, but you get the point.

the output ends with `ld: cannot find -lboost`.

Now i have seen something with using the `ln` command, but i am not sure what to link to what or why this problem occurs in the first place. I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: where _exactly_ are your boost binaries located, and what _exactly_ did you specify in your `-L` flag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The library Name specified in the -l flag turned out to be wrong.

Comment: what was it, and what was it supposed to be? ([answer])

Comment: I think it was -lboost_system or something. I'd have to Look it up on monday at work if you have the same problem and need the specific name.